# find the index of the smallest n numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

E.g. `l = [1,2,5,6,72,234,52,4,11]`

How can I find the indexes of the 3 smallest values?

The smallest 3 numbers are 1,2, and 4 so the desired output is `[0,1,7]`

I can only use python 2.7

Thanks

Comment: Have you made any attempt and written the code yourself? Stackoverflow isn't meant for solving assignment like problems.

Comment: @Karl this is not an assignments. It's extremely small part of assignment. I know how to do it by using `nsmallest` and then get index of each item. But I though there is a 'smarter' or quicker way to do it. thanks

Comment: Even if it is a small part of the assigment it is still asking a very broad question that you are expecting people to solve. If you have an attempt then please include it in your question and then people can help you with any problems related to that code. And "quicker" way to do something is a broad question as well, without seeing any code that could mean anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `heapq.nsmallest` instead:

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter
[i for i, _ in heapq.nsmallest(3, enumerate(l), key=itemgetter(1))]
```

This returns:

```
[0, 1, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method:

```
l = [1,2,5,6,72,234,52,4,11]
nsamllest = lambda l,n:map(lambda x:x[1],sorted([(x,i) for i,x in enumerate(l)],key=lambda x:x[0])[:n])
nsamllest(l,3)
```

output: [0,1,7]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the index of min/max within a list of numbers (which seems your case), then I suggest you use numpy:

mylist = [1,2,5,6,72,234,52,4,11]

```
import numpy as np
mindex = np.argmin(mylist)
```

OR

`maxinx = np.argmax(mylist)`